# Using async/await + Bluebird to promisifyAll

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, bluebird

I'm constructing a library that uses `async/await`, and I would like to know if it is possible to use native modules like `fs` with the `async/await`. I know that `async/await` it's just Promises in the background, so is there a native way to promisify a method or function? Currently I'm using the Bluebird, but I don't know if it's a bad pattern.

Example:

```js
    const Bluebird = require("bluebird");
    const { access } = require("fs");

    const accessAsync = Bluebird.promisify(access);

    async function checkInput(options) {
      await accessAsync(options.file);
      /// etc
      return options;
    }

    module.exports = (options) => {
      Promise.resolve(options)
        .then(checkInput)
    };
```

I'm combining both native Promises and Bluebird. Should I only use Bluebird?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I'm constructing a library that uses async/await, and I would like to know if it is possible to use native modules like fs with the async/await.

Yes. You can do it even simpler with Bluebird than in your example:

```
let fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));

// and in async function:
let contents = await fs.readFileAsync('file.txt', 'utf-8');
```

Note that you need to add `Async` at the end of the method names.

Or you can use the `mz` module, without needing to add `Async` to the methods. See:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/mz

There are many modules that you can require once you `npm install mz` - for example you can `require('mz/fs')` and it instantly lets you use the `fs` module version that returns promises instead of taking callbacks. Combined with async await it lets you do things like:

```
let fs = require('mz/fs');

// and in async function:
let contents = await fs.readFile('file.txt', 'utf-8');
```

The above code is still non-blocking.

See this answer where I show an example of `mz` version of the `crypto` module and explain it in more detail:

- **[Which functions could work as synchronous in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42169448/which-functions-could-work-as-synchronous-in-node-js/42169623#42169623)**

See example:

```
let crypto = require('mz/crypto');

async function x() {
  let bytes = await crypto.randomBytes(4);
  console.log(bytes);
}
```

You can do the same with many other modules, including:

- `child_process`
- `crypto`
- `dns`
- `fs`
- `readline`
- `zlib`

> I know that async/await it's just Promises in the background, so... is there a native way to promisify a method or function?

Soon Node.js will support that natively - see **PR #5020 Adding Core support for Promises**:

- https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/5020

but in the meantime you can use `mz`.

For more context see also the **Issue #7549 v1: executing async functions without callbacks should return promises**:

- https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/7549

See also the Node.js's **Promises Working Group Repository**:

- https://github.com/nodejs/promises

**Update:** It seems that the PR 5020 mentioned above is not going to land in Node.js any time soon - thanks to [Benjamin Gruenbaum for pointing it out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43096728/using-async-await-bluebird-to-promisifyall#comment73280632_43096840). So it seems that using Bluebird's `promisify` and `promisifyAll` and the helpful `mz` module will be the only easy way to use modern features of the language with the core modules of Node.js. Fortunately they work very well, so it's not a big problem.

Comment: brilliant ideia!

Comment: I hate to be a party pooper - #5020 isn't happening anytime soon. I founded the promises working group - sadly - it's not going anywhere at the moment due to the sheer amount of work involved. There is a chance `util.awaitable` will land though in the coming months.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thanks for the info. I updated the answer.

Comment: @celoxxx See my updated answer. I adder more info on Bluebird and the status of the pull request adding promise support to Node.

Answer (score 3):

By all means, Bluebird is *designed* to work with native promises. The use case you describe is not only supported - but is a design goal of Bluebird.

Bluebird's promises implement `then` according to the Promises/A+ specification, which is guaranteed to work with `await`. Moreover, you can pass native promises to Bluebird and it'll work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Using Bluebird as well as Promises is only increasing your overhead. It means Bluebird is sufficient enough to handle other promises.